# TypeORM Doesn't Update MySQL DB with JSON Fields

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

App Details:
Node.js
Nest.js (TypeScript & Express.js)
TypeORM
MySQL DB

We've got a MySQL DB connected to TypeORM. We're in the process of building an "update" endpoint, but no changes are happening. I'm suspecting that we aren't formatting the details correctly, but everything that I've read says our syntax is correct.

The reason that this is so confusing is because we've already got data in objects and arrays based on other entities being created.

Array Example.

```
// ENTITY FIELD
@Column({ type: 'json', nullable: true, default: null })
url?: string[];

// ENDPOINT BODY v1
"url": "https://google.com",
// ENDPOINT BODY v2
"url": ["https://google.com"],
```

Object Example.

```
// ENTITY FIELD
@Column({ type: 'json', nullable: true, default: null })
list?: ListOptions[];

// ENDPOINT BODY
"list": [{
  "name": "The Punisher",
  "price": 25.00,
  "description": "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
  "pageURL": "https://google.com"
}]
```

All other CRUD endpoints have been done for the MVP. Need this figured out so we can finalize the API's MVP. The below is a live example of a field in question. The TypeORM module has `logging: true` activated and only `select` queries are being run on these fields.

The object is actually an address field.

```
// interface 
export interface Address {
    line1: string;
    line2?: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    zip: string;
    country: string;
}

// entity 
@Column({ type: 'json', nullable: true, default: null })
address?: Address;
```

Data being sent in the body:

```json
"address": {
  "line1": "123 Main St.",
  "city": "Dallas",
  "state": "TX",
  "zip": "12345",
  "country": "USA"
}
```

Comment: #solution

1. Switched to a PostgreSQL DB. 
2. Changed all object and array fields to `jsonb` field type. 
3. Had to play with the JSON `stringify` and `parse` methods. 

What does that look like? 
On my HTTP methods, the transfer of data is done as a string. So, before we send the data on the endpoint from the front-end, we use `JSON.stringify()`. 
Once received in the back-end, we use `JSON.parse()` to convert it back to an array or object. We use these "new" values in the data for updating the record.